# Changing url inside file_get_contents everytime the php file being accessed

Tags: php, url, file-get-contents

I need help to create simple php | changing url inside file_get_contents everytime the php file being accessed

First load

```
<?php
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/page=1');
echo $homepage;
?>
```

everytime the page load the url change (in this case the page number + 1)

Second load

```
<?php
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/page=2');
echo $homepage;
?>
```

Third load

```
<?php
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/page=3');
echo $homepage;
?>
```

and so forth

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Store the previous counter value in a `.txt` file. Read the counter from `.txt` file and increment it. Then hit `file_get_contents`. Finally `fwrite` current counter value again in the same file.

Comment: can you give me the example in php code for that scenario?

Comment: Will this page be accessed by more than one person at a time? If so, using a text file won't work because multiple process could be trying to write to the same file at the same time. If there is just one person accessing it then you will be fine.

Comment: whats the alternative if this page be accessed by more than one person at a time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by maintaining the counter in a `txt` file. Create a a directory (name counter as per my example) and an empty file c.txt before running this process. We can do a check if file does not exist, then create a file. But in your case it seems to be called more frequently, so can avoid extra processing here.

Here's the code snippet,

```
// File where counter will be maintained. Change the path to the one desired
$filename = "/root/Desktop/counter/c.txt";
$handle = fopen($filename, "r"); // Open the file in read mode
$counter = fread($handle, filesize($filename)); //Read the file
fclose($handle); // Close file object

// Increment the counter if available else set it to 1
$count = !empty($counter) ? (int)$counter+1 : 1;

$homepage = file_get_contents("http://www.example.com/page=$count");
echo $homepage;

$handle = fopen($filename, "w"); // Open the file in write truncate mode
fwrite($handle, $count); // Store the counter in the file
fclose($handle); // Close file object
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but when i'm accessing the php it put the same number each line inside c.txt
    1
    1

Comment: YOU ROCKS DUDE. THANK YOU

Comment: Your're welcome. Upvote and accept the answer if it helped. Happy coding :)

Comment: I try to Upvote but it says "Votes cast by those with less than 125 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed posted score." Once again thank you.

Comment: Thank you. But please note @ryantxr comments too regarding single or multiple users. I have provided the solution keeping in mind it as a process/cron.

Comment: whats the solution please (as a process/cron) ?